# Unable to Access WSO2 Governance Registry Management console

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-governance-registry

I have installed WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Governance registry on the same server. Though I have changed the offset value for G-reg(to avoid port conflict), I'm unable to open the Management console of it. But APIM Mgmt console is accessible.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: What is the offset you have specified? And whats the URL you are trying to access? Are there any errors?

Comment: Offset is set to <Offset>7</Offset> for G-reg. URL is https://localhost:9450/carbon/ and my APIM Mgmt URL is https://localhost:9443/carbon/. There are no critical errors except the "localhost" took too long to respond thrown by browser.

Comment: HI Mathan can you check if there are any errors that is logged at startup or when you are trying to access the Greg console. If so please provide it.

Comment: It is possible that the Greg server is not fully started. On Greg startup logs do you see the management console URL : e.g :
=====
[2016-08-01 15:23:45,019]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://192.168.122.1:9450/carbon/

Comment: Hi Json, Please find the below error while starting the G-reg Server.                    [2016-08-01 15:26:16,457] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFacto
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GREG_HOME\wso2greg-5.2.0\wso2greg-5.2.0\bin\..
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocket

Comment: yes Jason, I'm able to see all the 3 URL's. Mgmt Console, G-reg Publisher and G-reg Store

Comment: HI Mathan, Can you please edit the question and paste the full stacktrace so we can get a better understanding.

Comment: Jason, it's too lengthy to paste here. so I will breakup and paste it here

Comment: [2016-08-01 15:26:11,167] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.Identity
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GREG_HOME\wso2greg-5.2.0\wso2greg-5.2.0\bin\..
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
  
[2016-08-01 15:26:16,457] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFacto
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GREG_HOME\wso2greg-5.2.0\wso2greg-5.2.0\bin\..
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)

Comment: [2016-08-01 15:26:16,566] ERROR {org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol} -  Failed t
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GREG_HOME\wso2greg-5.2.0\wso2greg-5.2.0\bin\..
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
[2016-08-01 15:26:16,675] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} -
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[org
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.startConnectors(CarbonTo
        at

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Catalina"
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 80 more

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GREG_HOME\wso2greg-5.2.0\wso2greg-5
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)

Comment: @MathanPrasath: You can update the ticket with the entire stacktrace. That'll be clear and helpful to Jason to find out the cause.

Comment: Entire stacktrace can't be pasted at one short as the text box will not allow. Hence broke down and pasted above.

Comment: Not in comment section. Edit the question and add it there.

Comment: I really have to appreciate both of you for your valuable time for helping me out. I sorted it out with my Architect  here. Issue was with the unzipped Product as files were missing after unzipping. Many thanks